# Delphi/Indy10 How to check an https URL is valid without downloading contents

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy10

Previously the URL I needed to check was http and I used TidTCPClient to emulate the http protocol to determine the file at the web server existed.  Now they have switched to https and I don't know how to do it.

Can I use TIdHTTP with the TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL hander, and then some Indy function to only determine the resource exists?  I have OpenSSL installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing `TIdTCPClient` code should continue to work if you simply assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to the client's `IOHandler`, change the client's `Port` to 443, and set the IOHandler's `PassThrough` to False. HTTPS is just HTTP over an SSL/TLS connection, it doesn't change HTTP itself.

But to answer your question, yes, you can switch to `TIdHTTP` if you want to. You can use the HTTP `HEAD` command (the `TIdHTTP.Head()` method) to check if a URL is valid without having to download a full resource.

Comment: I remember trying Head originally but it didn't work correctly with this server so implemented my own solution.    I didn't realize SSL was implemented at the TCP level. That is now working, thank you.

Comment: @Ross `HEAD` is intended to be usable for any resource that is accessible via `GET`. Though results will be unpredictable if the resource is dynamically generated.